# How to remove an item from gallery

Tags: android

I created a gallery of webviews in an android app.I want to remove previously selected view from this gallery.How is it possible?

Comment: posting some code will really help people who really wanna help, so post some code, describe the difficulty you are having and what kind of digging you have done before posting this question.

Comment: did you want to remove it on back press... your question is bit unclear..

Comment: I am sorry...I want to remove the previous one when the new one is loading. –

Answer (score 1):

remove it from array that attached to it's adapter then call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**UPDATE:**

Get item position with:

```
int index = gallery.getSelectedItemPosition();
galleryArray.remove(index);
galleryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I am sorry...I want to remove the previous one when the new one is loading.

Comment: What you mean by 'galleryArray'?Is it an array of webviews?Then how to create it.Sorry...I am a beginner.

Comment: so you must first take a look at this tutorial, ListView and Galleries work same to each other, so see it first. galleryArray is an array that hold classes provide gallery (listview) data.

[ListView(Gallery) Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: if you got the answer please check it.